# iOS Camera wobble from video recording

Tags: ios, iphone, video

I'm having ONE single pain in the ass problem with recorded video from the iPhone.

Building a lap timer app for recording HD video on track days, I've eliminated the possibility of vibrations from wind, suspension and crucially the iPhone mount, so it must the the camera settings right?, I simply don't know what to change

Here's an example of the offending video 'wobble' at stand still (with iOS stabilization enabled), watch from 2:07s:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=beair-rOMgw

Is it the autofocus?

- Focus
  enum {
  AVCaptureFocusModelLocked = 0,
  AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus = 1,
  AVCaptureFocusModeContinousAutoFocus = 2

I used the following settings for video above

- AVCaptureVideoStabilizationModeAuto:

It seem like there's software compensation for engine vibration/frequency at stand still, the lens (I know it's physically fixed) but some how is moving, I'm I crazy or what?

Can someone please guide me?

Comment: Did you find the reason ? Same problem here !!!